# Trying to create a Row Level Formula using TODAY

Tags: formula, reporting

```
IF(LAST_UPDATE GT TODAY()-90,"Red","Green")
```

This throws an error is there a way to have a row level formula using TODAY?

Comment: What is the error message?  GT is not a valid operator in [Salesforce formulas](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions.htm&language=en_US&type=5), you should be using ">" or "<"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `TODAY()` (and `NOW()`) in row-level formulas. "GT", though, you may want to replace with ">". Aside from that, first, check if LAST_UPDATE is just a date, or if it includes time of day. If the latter, you'll want to use DATEVALUE(LAST_UPDATE) to avoid a type mismatch. Second, check to make sure your formula is returning a text field (as opposed to a number, date, or datetime).

If those don't work, read the error message it gives you when you click "validate". Good habit to get into in any case.

Comment: And if I wanted to double up the check can this be done?

IF(DATEVALUE(Account.Verification_Date__c) < TODAY()-120,"Red",IF(DATEVALUE(Account.Verification_Date__c) < TODAY()-90,"Yellow","Green")

Comment: that looks fine Matt, except you'll need to add a closing bracket.